# Google Sheets vlookup + filter + concatenation

Tags: google-sheets, filter, concatenation, vlookup

please, i need an arrayformula formula to do this:

vlookup a value + then get me all the matches in different cells and concatenate the matches if possible

ok, i now i can use filter + transpose and get all the matches in columns, but what i need it to be an arrayformula, so far i can only do this cell by cell like:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B;A:A=E1))
```

to be search:
value1       vlookup value1,2,3 in this range, then get all matches and concatenate them if possible 
value2
value3

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

not what i was looking for but it works, not an array formula but cell by cell at least for a finite range

=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B;$A$2:$A=E2))